# LLC-Miss Report in the Linux Perf_Events

Tags: linux, trace, cpu-cache, perf, memory-access

I ran the following command in the shell:

```
sudo perf record -F 60000 -e LLC-misses:u mplayer video.mp4
```

After the program finished execution, I ran this command:

```
sudo perf report
```

The report shows the locations of code (in `MPlayer` and the associated shared libraries) in the userspace with the percentage of LLC misses. Is it possible to determine the origin of the misses? i.e., if they are instruction misses or data misses?

**One more question:** when I change `LLC-misses:u` to `LLC-misses:up` the generated report will be empty. What is wrong with the `PEBS` switch addition?

Comment: Yes you can use the offcore response facility (see chapter 18 of the Intel manual volume 3). The details and limitations depend on your processor. Regarding, `LLC-misses`, it is not a precise event.

Comment: Use the `mem_load_retired.l3_miss` event on Intel CPUs to find loads that missed in L3 cache.  (LLC misses can be lower if multiple loads miss in the same cache line at the same time: that still only results in one LLC-miss.)  That doesn't mean all the rest are instruction-fetch, though, because it doesn't include data stores.

Comment: Hi Peter. Here is a paper from a prestigious OS conference (`USENIX ATC 2013`): `https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc13/atc13-bi.pdf`. In this paper, the total number of accesses to the `DRAM` is required. Therefore, the counter that you mentioned above (`mem_load_retired.l3_miss`) is used. But based on your description, it does considers neither instruction reads nor data writes. Am I right?

Comment: One more question: Does `perf tools` support `mem_load_retired.l3_miss`? How should I determine if an event is precise or not?